# Content owner not enabled to use Youtube Content ID program to upload reference

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I can create asset successfully but when I was about to upload a reference to that asset using youtube_partner.references().insert(), it gives me this error.

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/partner/v1/references?onBehalfOfContentOwner=&uploadType=resumable&alt=json
>   returned "You are not enabled to use YouTubes Content ID program to
>   create fingerprints for this content.">

Comment: Are you sure your content owner has been enabled for Content ID matching? You should get in touch with your Strategic Partner Manager at Google to get this enabled.